# Generic interfaces and inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a base interface that looks like this

```
public interface IBaseWidget<T> where T: IBaseConfiguration
{
   void Configure(T configuration);
}
```

I then have child interfaces that look like this:

```
public interface ISpecificWidget : IBaseWidget<IChildSpecificConfiguration>
{
}
```

`IChildSpecificConfiguration` implements `IBaseConfiguration` I then have classes that look like this

```
public class SomeClass : ISpecificWidget
{
    public void Configure(IChildSpecificConfiguration configuration)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This all works fine and we will come back to this.

Where it starts to break down is that there are several different extensions of `IBaseWidget<T>` which means that there are several different `SomeClass`. Additionally SomeClass is only ever accessed via a facade so, based on a bunch of rules, I have a base facade that actually creates an instance of the necessary SomeClass.  Prior to making `IBaseWidget` generic as shown above, my base facade looked like the following:

```
public abstract class BaseFacade<T> where T IBaseWidget
{
     T Widget {get;set;}
     private void Init()
     {
        Widget = (T)Activator.CreateInstance("type");
     }
}
```

Facades for each implementation of IBaseFoo look like so:

```
public sealed class SomeFacade : BaseFacade<ISpecificWidget>
{
    private void DoSomething()
    {
       Widget.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Again, this works fine.  My problem is this: after making `IBaseWidget` generic I modified the base facade like so:

```
public abstract class BaseFacade<T> where T : IBaseWidget<IBaseConfiguration>
{
     T Widget {get;set;}
     IBaseConfiguration configuration; //IChildSpecificConfiguration passed in via constructor and assigned to variable
     private void Init()
     {
        Widget = (T)Activator.CreateInstance("type");
        Widget.Configure(configuration)
     }
}
```

This breaks the above implmentation of `SomeFacade` with the message:

> `ISpecificWidget` must be convertible to `IBaseWidget<IBaseConfiguration>`

My expectation is that when I defined `ISpecificWidget` like so:

```
public interface ISpecificWidget : IBaseWidget<IChildSpecificConfiguration>
{
}
```

it would be convertible to IBaseWidget but that is not the case.  I know that I could solve this by having bases for each specific implementation of a widget, but I am trying to keep this as generic as possible.  Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but I don't see the code for IBaseConfiguration.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that provides concrete examples of what these interfaces are supposed to do, it's not possible to answer the question. There's a good chance you simply can't accomplish precisely what you're trying to do, because of the lack of type variance in this particular scenario. People commonly attempt to use base/derived types as type parameters when doing so isn't and shouldn't be legal. You should read the many existing posts on the topic of generic type variance, see whether what you're trying to do should even be legal, and if so, improve the question (if not, just delete it)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could answer to your problem.

Add this interface:

```
public interface IBaseWidget
{
    void Configure(IBaseConfiguration configuration);
}
```

Then inherits from it:

```
public interface IBaseWidget<T> : IBaseWidget
    where T : IBaseConfiguration
{
    void Configure(T configuration);
}
```

And finally:

```
public abstract class BaseFacade<T> where T : IBaseWidget
{
    T Widget { get; set; }
    IBaseConfiguration configuration; //IChildSpecificConfiguration passed in via constructor and assigned to variable
    private void Init()
    {
        Widget = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof());
        Widget.Configure(configuration);
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class SomeClass : ISpecificWidget
{
    void IBaseWidget.Configure(IBaseConfiguration configuration)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Configure(IChildSpecificConfiguration configuration)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```